How to xfail fixture using indirect parametrization in pytest?
I have a test that passes through indirect parametrization the parameters to a fixture. One of the parameters is known to fail, during test setup (one of the fixtures). I want to expect the failure of this single parameter, in a way that pytest mark it as strict xfail.
However, when I try to use pytest.param with marks=pytest.mark.xfail argument and pass it in an indirect parametrization, pytest doesn't understand it needs to mark the test as xfail. Also, it ends up causing extra exceptions because the parameter is passed as ParameterSet object, instead of its value.
This is my test + parametrization:
values = [1, 2, 3]
bug_values = [pytest.param(4, marks=pytest.mark.xfail(reason="..."))]
dict_values = [{"key": value} for value in values] + bug_values
all_values = values + bug_values
parameters_merged = zip(all_values, dict_values)

@pytest.mark.parametrize("direct_parameter, my_fixture", parameters_merged, indirect=["my_fixture"])
def test(my_fixture, direct_parameter):
    # test logic

This is my fixture:
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def my_fixture:
    return method(**request.param)

Because it can't parse the pytest.param, it causes the following exception:
ERROR [100%]
test setup failed

    @pytest.fixture(scope="function")
    def my_fixture:
>       return method(**request.param)
E       TypeError: 
module.my_fixture() argument after ** must be a mapping, not ParameterSet

How can I mark the fixture as xfail using indirect parametrization?
I know I can create an if block and inside it use the inline pytest.xfail, but I am trying to avoid it for both not depend on value specific code and to keep it clean, let pytest do its work.
Thanks!

Usually you don't mark fixtures, you mark tests.
There are multiple solution approaches to this:
First Approach - mark via indirect fixture parametrization.
import pytest

ok_values = [1, 2, 3]
bug_values = [4]
all_values = zip(ok_values, bug_values)


@pytest.fixture
def bug_params(request):
    if hasattr(request, 'param') and request.param:
        request.applymarker(pytest.mark.xfail(strict=True))
        return request.param
    return []


@pytest.fixture
def regular_params(request, bug_params):
    return request.param + bug_params


@pytest.fixture
def do_something_with_params(regular_params):
    return regular_params[::-1]


@pytest.mark.parametrize(['regular_params', 'bug_params'], [
    [ok_values, []],
    [ok_values, bug_values]
], indirect=['regular_params', 'bug_params'], ids=['ok', 'bug'])
def test_marker_applied(regular_params, bug_params, do_something_with_params):
    assert do_something_with_params == [3, 2, 1]

Results in:
test_marker_applied[ok] 
test_marker_applied[bug] 

================== 1 passed, 1 xfailed, 10 warnings in 0.08s ===================
PASSED        [ 50%]XFAIL        [100%]


Second Approach - mark parametrization explicitly
Therefore a possible solution to your problem might be marking the parametrization itself via pytest.param:
@pytest.fixture
def indirect_params(request):
   return do_something(**request.params)

@pytest.mark.parametrize(['direct_params', 'indirect_params'],
[
    pytest.param(direct_p, indirect_p, marks=pytest.mark.xfail(strict=True))
], indirect=['indirect_params'])
def test_something(direct_params, indirect_params):
    assert direct_params != indirect_params


Third Approach - mark if known fixture is parametrized
or rather resort to "special" fixtures that upon parametrizing them, mark the test:
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(session, config, items):
    for item in items:
       # bug_values fixture was parametrized
       if hasattr(item, "callspec") and "bug_values" in item.callspec.params:
           if item.callspec.getparam("bug_values"):
               item.add_marker(pytest.mark.xfail(strict=True))

